# Unable to get to PHP interactive mode

Tags: php, debian

I'm running Debian Squeeze & am trying to get to the PHP interactive mode. (I've installed php5-cli along with the usual php install packages)
 Normally I would do this by running `php -a`  on this system I get the following, with no usual php prompt:

> **Interactive mode enabled**

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php Some other comments that might be helpful there too

Comment: look in your `php.ini` for `cli.pager`

Comment: I've searched my php.ini for cli.pager & cannot see anything. Can you give me any pointers on what I need to add to the ini file? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is missing out on a solution.

1. If you want a few short commands without a persistent environment, do

   ```
    while read -er line; do php -r "$line"; done
   ```
2. Get a different php, (via compiling or other means) which links to readline instead of libedit (this was not done in debian because someone involved in php packaging does not want readline's gpl to apply to php), or a newer version of php which has this bug fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is a Debian-specific bug: [#576218](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576218).

To summarize the comments from the bug report: 
There seems no easy workaround for this. However, Ubuntu and probably other distributions are not affected by this bug because they build PHP against `libreadline`. Debian does not use `libreadline`, but `libedit` due to licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile readline module yourself. With Debian Wheezy and PHP 5.4 I was able to fix this by doing this (run commands as root):

```
# apt-get install php5-dev libedit-dev libreadline-dev

# mkdir php && cd php
# apt-get source php5-cli
# cd php5-5.4.4/ext/readline
# phpize
# ln -s ../../sapi/
# ./configure
# make
# cp modules/readline.so /usr/lib/php5/<number like 20100525>/
# chmod -x /usr/lib/php5/20100525/readline.so
# echo 'extension=readline.so' > /etc/php5/mods-available/readline.ini
# cd /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
# ln -s ../mods-available/readline.ini 20-readline.ini
```

Now the PHP console should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this for Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin (based on Debian Wheezy) so:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-readline
```